# Properties of functors

Tags: category-theory

I want these functors to have the following properties, they seem a bit arbitrary though - so I was looking for sufficient "standard" properties of functors which imply them (such as full, faithful etc.)

Let $F:C \to D$ be a functor with the following property.
If $F(c)=F(c')$ then there exists a $f: c \to c'$ in $C$ such that $F(f)=\text{id}_{F(c)}$.

Let $G:C \to D$ be a functor with the following property.
For all $f:c \to c'$ in $C$, if $G(f)=\text{id}_{F(c)}$ then $f= \text{id}_{c}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Full implies the first property. Faithful does not *quite* imply the second, because different objects can be mapped to the same object.

Comment: The second one is basically a weak version of faithful + injective on objects. A strong form of that might be "monomorphism in the category of categories".

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful - in hindsight full should of been obvious for the first property. Unfortunately I can't use that $G$ is injective on objects, although I would like $G$ to be faithful if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question has been answered in the comments.

Regarding the second question: the property for G that you describe is called "reflection of identities". 
You can find in the [book](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) "The joy of cats" section 13.36 that a sufficient condition for it is that G "creates isomorphisms".